# Similarity Ratios in triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

> Triangle $ABC$ is given. Let $M$ and $N$ be points on its sides $BC$ and $AC$ respectively, such that   $BM/MC$ = $1/3$ and $AN/NC$ = $1/5$. If $O$ is the intersection point of $AM$ and $BN$, find the ratio $AO/OM$.

I drew BN and AM and I see that there is a similar triangle relation there; $\triangle ANO \sim \triangle BMO$. So I got the ratio:

$\frac{AO}{OM} = \frac{AN}{BN}= \frac{3}{5} NC/MC$.

If you take a triangle now, with sides: $BM=1, MC = 3, AN = 1, NC = 5$, it messes everything up.

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Menelaus' theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MenelausTheorem.html), we have
$$\frac{CB}{BM}\cdot\frac{MO}{OA}\cdot\frac{AN}{NC}=1.$$
So, $$\frac{AO}{OM}=\color{red}{\frac 45}.$$

Comment: (+1) how did you set up Menelaus' here? I thought you needed a transverse line etc...

Comment: @Amad27: You can replace $A,B,C,D,E,F$ in the linked page with $C,M,A,B,O,N$ respectively.

Comment: @Amad27: You can see it in the following way : we have a triangle $ACM$ and a line $BON$. So, $$\frac{\color{red}{C}\color{blue}{B}}{\color{blue}{B}\color{red}{M}}\cdot\frac{\color{red}{M}\color{blue}{O}}{\color{blue}{O}\color{red}{A}}\cdot\frac{\color{red}{A}\color{blue}{N}}{\color{blue}{N}\color{red}{C}}=1.$$

Comment: Just one thing, how did you find $CB/BM$?

Comment: Since $BM:MC=1:3$, we have $CB:BM=1+3:1$, i.e $CB/BM=4/1=4$.

Comment: Not gonna lie, what motivated you to even manipulate Menlaus? Great thinking BTW

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30491/discussion-between-mathlove-and-amad27).

Comment: I have a really bad internet connection, thanks for your help. I wrote there too if you get the message. Your method and solution is great.

Comment: @Amad27: You are welcome, and thank you.

Comment: I got an answer too, but the method does not require the intuition as this does; I still like your solution though

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer too. Inspired from Jack D'Aurizio's answer in my other question.

[Van Obel](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/Gergonne.shtml) and Ceva's theorem is used.

The problem gives: $BM/MC = 1/3, AN/NC = 1/5$

Let there be a point $F$ on $AB$ such that $CF$ intersects at $O$ as well. Then, by Ceva:

$\frac{AF}{FB} \cdot \frac{BM}{MC} \cdot \frac{CN}{NA} = 1 \implies \frac{AF}{FB} = \frac{3}{5}.$

By Van Obel's theorem, $\frac{AO}{OM} = \frac{AF}{FB} + \frac{AN}{NC} \implies \frac{AO}{OM} = 1/5 + 3/5 = \frac{4}{5}$ as @mathlove got.